# Unable to disable ssl verification in cURL

Tags: rest, ssl, curl, restful-url

I have exposed some **ReSTFul** web services on a corporate network [ Company's Internal Network]. I am trying to test those using **curl** on **windows**. The address of the GET request is something like this --> (http**s** on **non standard port**)
[https://myCompanysNet:**13432**/something/something/1.0.0/](https://myCompanysNet:13432/something/something/1.0.0/)

```
curl -H "Accept:application/xml" --user username:password "https://myCompanysNet:13432/something/something/1.0.0/"
```

And I have added option **insecure** in *curlrc* conf. file
But instead of getting the required XMLs in the response , the output is some html page showing the following error

```
HTTPS Request Blocked
```

`Your request has been blocked by because it is not allowed to use HTTP CONNECT method to port 13432. This may be due to the use of a non-standard HTTPS port`.

Which is the same error page , when one tries to open restricted websites via company's network !

I have a client code written in java , which works quite fine and fetches the XMLs , but the requirement is to use curl.

**EDIT 1 :-**
Following method is called in java client code:

```
static {
    disableSslVerification();
}

private static void disableSslVerification() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: *Which is the same error page , when one tries to open restricted websites via company's network !* Could it be that you have configured curl to use some kind of a proxy when it shouldn't? Obviously the insecure option is working since curl itself does not produce an error.

Comment: Try running it with `--noproxy myCompanysNet` to see if that's the case.

Comment: That was fast answer !! It worked fine.. May be curl was using system proxy variables that I had set! thnx