# How to invoke a https URL without disabling ssl verification?

Tags: java, url, ssl, https

I have written some code in Java using the java.net.URL class for reading content from a url.
[Using java net url connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).

The URL is a secured URL (https).

For now, I have used the suggestion in this answer [Dissable SSL Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537098/unable-to-disable-ssl-verification-in-curl).

But I want to do this properly (i.e not dissable ssl verification). How do I achieve this? What are the steps I need to take to achieve this?

This might have been answered already, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You need to install the SSL certificate from the host you're trying to access onto your machine. It's just the same with using a browser, if the SSL on the host isn't verifiable then you would need to add an exception. Depending on what OS you use, you can do this fairly easily.

Comment: If the server doesn't have a CA-signed certificate, complain to them about it. If you are 'them', fix it. There are ways to handle self-signed certificates, but even in the short term, let alone the long term, they are more expensive and less secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server uses a valid (signed by an CA) certificate, your code should not make any problems.
If the server doesn't use a valid certificate you may import that certificate into your cacerts file of your client jvm:

```
keytool
    -import
    -alias <provide_an_alias>
    -file <certificate_file>
    -keystore <your_path_to_jre>/lib/security/cacerts
```

where `<certificate file>` is the certificate fetched from the webserver. 
However, this should only be done when connecting to a test environment.