# Selenium webdriver java code is not using customized firefox profile

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

1) My Firefox is installed on following path `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` 
    2) I'm using Windows 7 64 bit version. 
   3) I'm using Firefox 46.0 version.  
  4) I'm using selenium-java-2.53.0 version. 
   5) Firefox profile is located on `C:\Users\xxxxxx\automation`

I created separate profile and tried to use same in code but still web driver is creating in anonymous temporary profile only. Please help me on this issue.

I have done these ways.

First Method

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("automation");    
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();    capability.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, myprofile);   
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capability);
```

Second method

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();    
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("automation");   
driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Third Method

```
FirefoxProfile myprofile =profile.getProfile("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\NewProfile");driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Fourth Method

```
FirefoxProfile myprofile=new FirefoxProfile(new File("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\NewProfile"));driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

**Note:**    When I'm executing following command 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p' its showing 2 profile is available first is `default` and another one is I created for Automation in the name of `automation` and able to launch manually without any issues.

But when automation runs i executed  "about:support" in firefox address bar and  reviewed the profile folder its showing anonymous temporary profile only.

Comment: Instead of passing "automation" , provide path to the profile. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467460/firefox-error-your-connection-is-not-secure-while-launching-driver-with-selen/40882513#40882513)

Comment: Even i tried same but still creating new anonymous temporary profile, Please help me

Comment: Having this exact same issue. I've tried all of the above methods and I'm still getting a temporary profile. Windows 10 64bit, Firefox 55, selenium java 3.5.2