# Java throws Exception :Selenium 3.4.0,Gecko driver 16.01,FF 53.01

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

When run,java throws following exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=A.
Im using gecko driver 16.1.When I use gecko 14.01 its navigating till gmail page and then not able to find element even when I set implicit wait.

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    public class login {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/asdf/Desktop/selenium/gecko32/geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities);
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //  Wait For Page To Load
        // Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // Navigate to URL
    driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // gmail login
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

`SessionNotCreatedException` can be observed for different reasons, such as **`Selenium-geckodriver`** version mismatch, dangling **`geckodriver`** instances and **`OS chores`**. I will suggest you to consider the following steps:

1. From `Task Manager` kill all the dangling `geckodriver` instances manually/programatically. If possible restart your system. If needed, run the `CCleaner` to wipe away all the unwanted OS chores from your system.
2. Download [**`Selenium Standalone Server 3.4.0`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) or [**`Selenium Client 3.4.0`**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-java-3.4.0.zip) from this [page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
3. Download **`geckodriver v.0.16.1`** from this [page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).
4. Ensure you have installed the latest stable GA version of `Mozilla Firefox` 53.0
5. The `MarionetteDriver` implementation is discontinued, you can consider using the `FirefoxDriver` implementation.
6. For a detailed discussion on `MarionetteDriver` and `GeckoDriver` you can consider having a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver/43920453#43920453).
7. Here is your own code which executes well with some minor tweaks:

   ```
   package demo;

   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

   public class Q44351100_SessionNotCreatedException 
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/your_directory/geckodriver.exe");
           DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
           capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys("username");
       }
   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Hii!Thanks a lot for the detailed solution.I have done all,and I tried running your code.Its navigating till the gmail  page,but not able to use send keys and send the username to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest versions of Firefox browser and gecko driver. Hope this helps

Comment: As I have mentioned I am using latest Firefox 53.0 ,and latest gecko 16.01

Comment: Use geckodriver v0.16.1

Comment: Also upgrade your selenium version to 3.4.0

Comment: Yes As I have mentioned in the title I'm using the latest

Comment: try using firefoxdriver instead of marionette driver and that too without capabilities

Comment: But I thought for selenium 3 and above we need to use marionette as Im using java(Eclipse) to run it.

Comment: Thats not true!

Comment: I used w/0 marionette and  used gecko 14.Still its going only till the gmail page.Getting Exception :Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string

Comment: there is some problem in gecko 14 in using send keys, use gecko version 0.16.1

Comment: When I use 0.16.1 (64 bit)with Selenium 3.40 and FF 53 I get this:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@27808f31, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOption

Comment: same is working fine for me. Please paste your updated code

Answer (score 0):

Initiate FirefoxDriver instead of marionette driver.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I did as you said .I got this exception :Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@545997b1, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@545997b1,

Comment: did you got any error message for this.... WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();;

Comment: yes the same error.As everybody suggested im using latest selenium and gecko v0.16.01.But gecho 14 is working till login page.But its not able to use sendkeys

Comment: It works in my machine. I am sure that we need to use firefox driver instead of marionetter. I am using selenium 3.2, firefox 13 and gecko 0.14.

Comment: im using FF 53,selenium 3.4.0 and gecko v 0.16.1.I tried with your seuugestion too ,still showing the same error.Im using eclipse kepler with jdk 1.8.No errors seen on code

Comment: can you try reinstalling FF