# How can Geckodriver/Firefox work without Marionette? (running python selenium 3 against FF 53)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, marionette, geckodriver

I'm seeing a bizarre "untrusted cert" error only on selenium-controlled firefox pop-ups. Very specific. To solve this problem, various google results suggested turning off marionette, like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

And this works, but how?? How is geckodriver working at all with Marionette off?

From [this other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver):

> Marionette is an automation driver for Mozilla's Gecko engine.

The answer goes on to explicitly say it should fail:

> "In case of using the Firefox 53.x browsers if you forcefully set "marionette" to false through DesiredCapabilities class you will observe a UnreachableBrowserException."

So, how the heck is this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have take care of a couple of things as follows:

1. `"untrusted cert" error only on selenium-controlled firefox pop-ups` : This is a common issue and we can avoid that through configuring the `WebDriver` instance through `DesiredCapabilities` class.
2. `turning off marionette` : Turning off `marionette` is no more a solution while we work with Selenium 3.x and recent Mozilla Firefox Browser releases. By forcefully setting **"marionette"** to false through DesiredCapabilities class you won't be able to open Mozilla Firefox Browser above version 48.x.
3. About your code, I don't see any significant errors in your code. You have set **"marionette"** to false through `DesiredCapabilities` class but still works and open a Mozilla Firefox Browser session of legacy releases which is also installed on your machine which is below version 48.x
4. To do a quick test, I simply copied your code and opened the url `https://www.whatismybrowser.com/`.

**Code**:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

    firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = False
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/')
```

**Result**: Mozilla Firefox version 47 is opened.

[image]

5. Now as per Selenium 3.4.x specifications, I made a couple of modifications. Turned **"marionette"** to true and added `executable_path` while initializing the driver.

> It is to be noted that the current Selenium-Python binding is unstable with geckodriver and looks to be Architecture specific. You can find the github [discussion](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884) and [merge](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/pull/685) here. So you may additionally need to pass the absolute path of the firefox binary as `firefox_binary` argument while initializing the **webdriver**

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,executable_path='C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.whatismybrowser.com/')
```

**Result**: Mozilla Firefox version 53 is opened.

[image]