# UnreachableBrowserException firefox driver selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am having a problem with geckodriver (FF) in java-selenium.
I am running multiple test scenarios via TEST-NG parallel execution (6+ threads).

Sometimes happens that at the start (opening new browser) I get unreachableBrowserException. So i try-catch it, waited 100ms and try to create it again. it works, but it keeps the first failed browser opened, with a blank page.

Problem is that the first window got opened BEFORE it got initialized as a driver, so it cannot be closed by driver.close() or something (it is null). So I have to close them manually.

So, my question is, has anyone encountered such behaviour? 
How can i close such browsers, without influencing the other threads?

```
while(true) {
            try {
                setDriver(DriverFactory.createInstance(getBrowserInstance()));
                break;
            } catch (UnreachableBrowserException e) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                log.info("UnreachableBrowserException! Needed to wait for 100ms ");
                removeDriver();
                counter++;
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                log.info("Thread could not wait!");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(counter>100){
            log.info("Was not able to create a browser session!");
            break;
        }
    }
```

and the part of .createInstance :

```
final ProfilesIni profilesIni = new ProfilesIni();
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers/geckodriver.exe");
                System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"false");
                firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
                firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
                firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
                firefoxProfile.setPreference("app.update.auto", false);
                firefoxProfile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
                firefoxProfile = profilesIni.getProfile("selenium_profile");
                capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);

                return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities); //Here it throws the exception.
```

Selenium/Java/geckodriver versions are most recent. FF version is unfortunately 44.02 (cannot get newer).
I would be grateful for any tips/hints.

Kind regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Mozilla Firefox version 44.02 and cannot get newer you have to consider a lot of things.

1. To use `Selenium 3.x` you have to mandatory use `geckodriver`. See why [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697).
2. Firefox 44.02 is not marionette enabled, so you have to set `marionette` to **`false`** through **`DesiredCapabilities`** class. See why [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3/44537094#44537094)
3. There are couple of **`Selenium`** version dependencies and **`GeckoDriver`** version dependencies. See them [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453)
4. You cannot create a new `Firefox Profile` and then again try to use a existing `Firefox Profile`.
5. Assuming you have a existing `Firefox Profile` by the name `selenium_profile`, the following code would open the Firefox Profile in a new browser session:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
   ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
   FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = profile.getProfile("selenium_profile");
   firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
   firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("app.update.auto", false);
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
   dc.setCapability("marionette", false);
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   ```

Now you can easily return the capabilities.