# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with GeckoDriver, Selenium and Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have developed a python script with selenium with firefox webdriver. It is workign fine in my machine. but if i execute the same script in another machine it is giving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insurance_web_monitor.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver', firefox_options=options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 167, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", l
ine 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a
 matching set of capabilities
```

Here is my code

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expected
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = Options()
    cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    cap["marionette"] = False
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    driver = Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver', firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
    driver.get('http://www.google.com')
    driver.save_screenshot(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.getcwd(), 'screenshot1.png'))
    wait.until(expected.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'q'))).send_keys('headless firefox' + Keys.ENTER)
    wait.until(expected.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ires a'))).click()
    print(driver.page_source)
    driver.quit()
```

The configurations in my machine are,

```
Windows => 7 Professional 64-bit
Python => 3.4.4
Selenium => 3.14
Firefox => 61.0.2
geckodriver => 0.21.0
```

The configurations in other machine are,

```
Windows => 7 Professional 64-bit
Python => 3.4.4
Selenium => 3.14
Firefox => 61.0.2
geckodriver => 0.21.0
```

Yes every configuration is exactly same. Though this seems silly it is not working and it's torturing me.
Am i missing anything to consider between the machines? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `caps['marionette'] = False`

Comment: @SmashGuy Update the question with the error trace log.

Comment: @NarendraR, yes. But that is leading to `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Possible firefox version mismatch` error.  Modified the code in question

Comment: @DebanjanB added the error log

Comment: As you are using `Firefox => 61.0.2` you can't use the configuration `cap["marionette"] = False`. Keep the configuration of `marionette` as **default** (`true` by default).

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for the information. But any solution for my question?

Answer (score 1):

As per your question and code block as you are using the following *Test Configuration*:

- Selenium => 3.14
- geckodriver => 0.21.0
- Firefox => 61.0.2

You have to use the capability **marionette** mandatorily. To achieve that either:

- You can leave the capability **marionette** untouched as by default `marionette` is set to **True**.
- You can also specify the capability **marionette** as follows:

  ```
  cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
  cap["marionette"] = True
  ```

---

### This usecase

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

There are numerous possibilities behind the error you are seeing and can be solved through any of the following steps mentioned below:

- As you are on *Windows OS* you need to pass the *key* **executable_path** along with the *value* containing:

  - *Absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver*.
  - The *Absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* should be mentioned through single quotes and single backward slash along with the raw (`r`) switch.
  - Include the extension of the *GeckoDriver* binary.
  - Your line of code will be:

    ```
    driver = Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap)
    ```

---

### References

- [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities with Firefox 46 through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782650/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-unable-to-find-a)
- [How can Geckodriver/Firefox work without Marionette? (running python selenium 3 against FF 53)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3)

Comment: +1 for your time and explanation. Thanks. But this also doesn't work. I am unable to sort the error out.