# How to properly use selenium with geckodriver and firefox with python on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to use the geckodriver with firefox and selenium on my Ubuntu machine. This is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver


#path where browser is installed
binary = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = binary
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--headless')


cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False


path_to_driver = "/home/andrea/geckodriver"

# run firefox webdriver from executable path 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path = path_to_driver)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path = path_to_driver)


driver.get("https://www.amboss.com/us/account/login")
```

Despite that I am getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. 
Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpuigrk9f7 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

The firefox version which I work with is:
`Mozilla Firefox 68.0.2`

Does anyone have any idea as to how I could go about fixing this?

Comment: Is that downloaded driver located in `"/home/andrea/geckodriver"` from [this page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)? Is it an executable (`chmod +x`)?

Comment: @ipaleka yes it even opens mozilla firefox but then it closes and the console displayes the error message I wrote above

Comment: Have you tried with this brand new driver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases?

Answer (score 6):

**Step1: Install Selenium**

Type in Terminal(in Ubuntu) or in Command Prompt(in Windows)

```
$pip install selenium
```

**Step2: Download Geckodriver**

In order to work with Selenium there should be an executable called 'Gecko Driver' installed.

Download Gecko Driver from the following page:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

**Step3: Install Gecko Driver**

Latest version for Windows:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64.zip

Latest version for Ubuntu:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz

Setup Gecko Driver For Windows:
Extract the zip file and move the geckodiver.exe executable file to any location which is already in Path variable(For Example you can move it to Python path location)

Unless add the path of 'geckodriver.exe' to the Path variable

Setup Gecko Driver For Ubuntu:
Open Terminal

```
Ctrl+Alt+T
```

move directory to the location where tar file is downloaded
Usually it will be in Downloads. so type $ cd Downloads

Unzip the tar file
eg:

```
$sudo tar -xvf filename.tar.gz
```

In my case it is:

```
$sudo tar -xvf geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

Move the geckodriver executable file to the '/usr/local/bin' location
$sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/

Move the directory to '/usr/local/bin/'

```
$cd /usr/local/bin/
```

Now make executable permission for 'geckodriver' executable file

```
$sudo chmod +x geckodriver
```

Now type 'geckodriver' in Terminal

```
geckodriver
```

If Gecko Driver is not working still then add its path

```
$export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

Now it is ready to work with selenium

**Sample Code**

Some sample codes are here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
page_url=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='content']")
all_title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("title")
title = [title.text for title in all_title]
print(title)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. 
Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpuigrk9f7 If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

...implies that there was a mismatch between the *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox* version while initiating/spawning a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *Mozilla Firefox v68.0.2*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is is unknown to us.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is unknown to us.

However as you are using *Mozilla Firefox v68.0.2*, using *GeckoDriver* is **mandatory** and while you use *GeckoDriver* you can't set the *capability* **marionette** as **`False`**.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How can Geckodriver/Firefox work without Marionette? (running python selenium 3 against FF 53)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3/44537094#44537094)

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to current [**GeckoDriver v0.24.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the specified location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v68.0.2*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Outro

### [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Firefox with Selenium, you need to import e Firefox Profile. You can use your own Profile through the following steps :

1. Locate the Firefox Profile directory
2. You have to specify the absolute path of the Firefox Profile directory when you initiate the `webdriver`.

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(*path to your profile*)
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
   ```

Comment: found it, but this didnt work! it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Step1:  Install Selenium  Type in Terminal (in Ubuntu)

```bash
$ pip install selenium
```

Step2: Download Geckodriver

```
https://pypi.org/project/geckodriver-autoinstaller/
```

Step3: Inside your python code file

```py
from selenium import webdriver                  # Import selenium into your program
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # Import keys of selenium web driver
import geckodriver_autoinstaller                # import Geckodriver into your program
geckodriver_autoinstaller.install()             # Get the latest version every day on 1st excution of your program
driver = webdriver.Firefox()                    # initiate the firefox driver 
driver.get("Your Website URL")
```