# Setting up Selenium and Geckodriver on Ubuntu to use with Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I'm having troubles setting up Geckodriver to run with Selenium on a Ubuntu VPS,  [referring to this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870311/how-to-properly-use-selenium-with-geckodriver-and-firefox-with-python-on-ubuntu).

My current setup:

- Selenium Version: 4.17.2
- Firefox Version: 122.0
- Geckodriver Version: 0.34.0
- Python Version: 3.8.10
- Ubuntu Version: 20.04.5 LTS

Steps:

1. Installing all the necessary packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

```
pip install selenium
```

```
tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.34.0-linux64.tar.gz
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

The last command puts geckodriver on PATH, this is needed according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

2. Verifying installation

```
firefox --version
```

```
./geckodriver --version
```

```
pip show selenium
```

3. Executing a test script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

This works like a clock on a local Windows machine but on a headless Ubuntu VPS returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Where did I go wrong?
Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're incorrectly setting headless mode. And you appear to be spinning up the browser twice (once without options). Use this for setting headless mode correctly:

```py
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Your full script would look like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried your changes - it still runs on my local Windows machine just fine, although it now properly works in headless mode but on linux VPS it still doesn't work. The error message is different now however "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette". Any idea what causes it?

Comment: Now you have this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49734915/7058266 (See the solutions there)

Comment: True, I will post an update to my question once I upgrade RAM in my VPS to help other community members with the same problem