# Linux machine with Firefix 52: I don't have geckoDriver.exe and Selenium tests stills runs fine

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I followed the steps according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43899952/7282061 and still could not run tests in windows 7 machine with Firefox 54.0.1 installed. It opened the browser but did not run tests without the Gecko driver.

But it worked without the Gecko driver in a Linux machine that had Firefox 52 and Selenium 2.52, irrespective of whether I set marionette to true or false in DesiredCapabilities!!! Can someone please explain? Selenium 2.52 supports newer Firefox versions without this geckoDriver?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You have mentioned about 1. `opened the browser but did not run tests without the Gecko driver`, 2. `worked without the Gecko driver in a Linux machine that had Firefox 52 and Selenium 2.52` 3. `irrespective of whether I set marionette to true or false in DesiredCapabilities`. 4. `Selenium 2.52 supports newer Firefox versions without this geckoDriver`. Consider narrowing down your Question please.

Comment: I was using Firefox 46 and Selenium 2.52 and tests were running fine. I thought upgrading to Firefox 52 will break the tests since newer Firefox version need GeckDriver. How come tests are running fine with newer 52 version in a Linux machine? I did not make any changes to config or system property to point to gecko driver.