# Selenium : The browser is getting opened but not able to get URL in the browser

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

OS:Windows 10

Execution Environment : JavaSE-1.8 (jre1.8.0_144)

JARs and class folders on build path:
client-combined-3.6.0-sources.jar
client-combined3.6.0.jar
selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar

Browser:
FireFox 56.0

Code Snippet:
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:/Users/admin/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver ();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

Error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:112)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:97)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:217)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
at FacebookFriends.main(FacebookFriends.java:18)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:45149/hub/status] to be available after 45005 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:110)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
... 9 more
```

Comment: You can try this System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Users/admin/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32/geckodriver.exe")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all You are using a little bit old version of gecko driver. The newest from: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Then You need to set up system property with:

```
File gecko = new File("C:/Users/admin/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.19.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");    
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", gecko.getAbsolutePath());
```

If You really want to use marionette check answers on: [Difference between webdriver.firefox.marionette & webdriver.gecko.driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver)

Answer (score 1):

I haved this error for 2 days, the solution for me was in Set.Plataform put Platafor.ANY or Plataform.Windows because Plataform.WIN10 not worked, marionette wasn't necessary and I added and neether works, only works this. I hope this helps someone else:

public class Main {
    public static RemoteWebDriver driver;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/Lib/geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();
    desiredCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://172.20.19.182:5557/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
    driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("execute automation");
    driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    driver.close();
    // write your code here
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using double `\\` in the path of the geckodriver.

Also instead of using :

```
System.setProperty(
    "webdriver.firefox.marionette",
    "C:/Users/admin/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32/geckodriver.exe");
```

Can you try using

```
System.setProperty(
    "webdriver.gecko.driver",
    "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Title : Problem Resolved
Solution Accepted : 
- Use latest version of gecko driver

Code Used
- System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\Marionette\geckodriver_1.exe" );