# Selenium 3.11, gecodriver 0.20.1, Firefox 60.0.2 shows SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver

Hi we have following scenario: I want wo start my test case on Selenium Grid the machine is a Win 10 machine. If I set the capability through *Desired Capabilities* to marionette=**false**, selenium opens the browser and then a time-out exception occurs. But if I set the capability to marionette=**true** or skip it a session is not created exception occurs. 
I already tried to use FirefoxOptions to set the capabilities but the problem still occurs, with Chrome we have no problems its working perfect. As in many other questions answered before we should skip marionette setting, because we are using the geckogriver 0.20.1 and FF higher 53.X, but this does not work in my case and setting marionette to false the browser opens and then nothing happens. I have already checked my paths to the geckodriver which are set in the run command like this:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\Users\root\Desktop\SeleniumGrid\geckodriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig config.json
```

The config.json looks like:

```
{"capabilites":{ "browserName": "firefox", "maxInstances": 4, "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver}, "nodeTimeout": 240, "nodePolling": 2000, "maxSession": 4, "timeout": 30000, "port": 6435, "register": true, "registerCycle": 5000, "cleanUpCycle": 2000, "hub": "http://sampleurlcom:4444"}
```

**In the following I will add my sample code:**

```
capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
capabilities.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
capabilities.setBrowserName(browserOS.getBrowser());
capabilities.setPlatform(browserOS.getOS());
return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://sampleurl.com:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

**Thats stacktrace if marionette is not set or set to true:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'SENODE3-WIN10', ip: '172.16.30.23', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 
Command duration or timeout: 810 milliseconds

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:145)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.SeleniumGrid.getWebDriver(SeleniumGrid.java:51)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.WebDriverFactory.createRemoteWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:101)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.WebDriverFactory.createRemoteWebDriverInstances(WebDriverFactory.java:50)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.testng.AbstractSeleniumTest.setUp(AbstractSeleniumTest.java:44)
    at de.telekom.ess.it.selenium.help.functional.ESSHelpIT.setUp(ESSHelpIT.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:637)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:605)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'SENODE3-WIN10', ip: '172.16.30.23', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'Rohit.local', ip: '172.16.34.213', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.RemoteSession$Factory.performHandshake(RemoteSession.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$12(ActiveSessionFactory.java:176)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.apply(ActiveSessionFactory.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$2(NewSessionPipeline.java:65)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$3(NewSessionPipeline.java:68)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$1(WebDriverServlet.java:246)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**The stacktrace if marionette is set false and the browser opens but nothing else happens:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'SENODE3-WIN10', ip: '172.16.30.23', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 46.03 seconds

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:145)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.SeleniumGrid.getWebDriver(SeleniumGrid.java:51)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.WebDriverFactory.createRemoteWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:101)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.WebDriverFactory.createRemoteWebDriverInstances(WebDriverFactory.java:50)
    at de.cybercon.selenium.testng.AbstractSeleniumTest.setUp(AbstractSeleniumTest.java:44)
    at de.telekom.ess.it.selenium.help.functional.ESSHelpIT.setUp(ESSHelpIT.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:637)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:605)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1062)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:974)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
```

Already tried solutions:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //Location where Firefox is installed

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options);
//set more capabilities as per your requirements
```

[The solution is from a tutorial.](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/http://)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try after updating to latest selenium, geckodriver and firefox

Comment: Hi @Ranjith's just tried with selenium 3.12, firefox 60.0.2 and geckodriver 0.21.0 still the same results as before, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you need to address:

- When you work with **Selenium 3.11**, **GecoDriver 0.20.1** and **Firefox 60.0.2** setting **`marionette=false`** is no more an option. **`marionette=true`** is set by default or you can explicitly mention it too.
- Here you will find some relevant references:

  - [Difference between webdriver.firefox.marionette & webdriver.gecko.driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver/43920453#43920453)
  - [Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697)
- The command to start the **Selenium Grid Node** through `-nodeConfig` argument is as follows:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:/Users/root/Desktop/SeleniumGrid/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
  //    ^ observe the argument D
  ```
- As you are using `-nodeConfig` argument you can tweak the parameters a bit as follows:

  ```
  {
  "capabilities": [
      {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 4,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
      },
  ],
      "nodeTimeout": 240,
      "nodePolling": 2000,
      "maxSession": 4,
      "cleanUpCycle": 2000
      "port": 6435,
      "host": <provide ip>,
      "register": true,
      "registerCycle": 5000,
      "hubPort": 4444,
      "hubHost": 10.174.1.51,
      "timeout": 30000,
      "browserTimeout":60
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB the -D argument was a misspelling while coping the code, but the changes of the parameter didn't helped me a lot I still have the same error