# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary using webdriver.firefox.marionette

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

```
public class TestClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin");

        driver.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This code is results in the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 

      [
        {
          "id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}",
          "minVersion":"63.0","maxVersion":"63.*"
        }
      ],
      "targetPlatforms":[],
      "seen":true,
      "dependencies":[],
      "hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,
      "userPermissions":null,
      "icons":{},
      "blocklistState":0,
      "blocklistURL":null,
      "startupData":null,
      "hidden":true,
      "location":"app-system-defaults"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

1. Make sure that your FF version is 63 (the latest on Oct 30, 2018)
2. Make sure your selenium version is 3.14
3. Make sure that you have downloaded latest geckodriver 0.23 (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
4. Make sure geckodriver.exe is in the root of C:\\ (or change the path below)
5. Use: `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");`

If it does not work, try downgrading your FF to a previous 62 version and give it a try.

FYI read this [Difference between webdriver.firefox.marionette & webdriver.gecko.driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272919/difference-between-webdriver-firefox-marionette-webdriver-gecko-driver)

Supported versions:
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html

Comment: @JerryGeorge it would be helpful for other users if you share which step helped you... or provide some more details if none of them helped ;).

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Selenium 3.x*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox* you need to download the latest required version of **GeckoDriver** from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), extract it and mention the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* binary through `System.setProperty()` line through the *Key* **`webdriver.gecko.driver`** instead of `webdriver.firefox.marionette` as follows:

```
public class TestClass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin");
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Note**: Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

### [Supported Platforms](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html#supported-platforms)

The following table shows a mapping between geckodriver releases, supported versions of Firefox, and required Selenium version:

[image: GeckoDriver_SupportedPlatforms_small]